# Outlook Style Android App

Tags: email, outlook, samsung-galaxy-note

I use 2010  Outlook running on a PoP3 server.  I just bought a Galaxy  Note and love it.  But I need an e-mail app like outlook that will allow me to setup folder and rules to move specific e-mail in their correct folders.  I don't care about syncing with Outlook on my window x64 O.S. because my server handles that for me.  But I need the portability  of my note with a sort of sophisticated folder/rule e-mail app.  I don't mind paying for it, as long as it just doesn't delete my mail after 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Touchdown](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nitrodesk.droid20.nitroid&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS5uaXRyb2Rlc2suZHJvaWQyMC5uaXRyb2lkIl0.). Their [feature list](http://www.nitrodesk.com/features.aspx) includes "Email Folders" and allows for rules/filters (per [this thread](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-general-discussions/64958-message-filtering.html)). If you like it, make sure to buy a licence before the 30-day trial is up.

I'm not an Exchange-on-Android user myself, but of those I know who are many prefer Touchdown.

Comment: Thanks I will look at it. I am a believer in purchasing software.